# How to efficiently Parse Json to Object when different variables returned in each json string

Tags: java, json

I need some advice on JSON parsing in Java. For some real-time update, i get JSON response like following (server returned only the variables that has new values):

```
{"33":"7153", "170":"AA","151":10}
{"33":"7153","rate":0.5488,"45":"U05"}
{"33":"7153", "98":7.38,"132":583}
```

Any idea how do I efficiently write a parser to parse them to object instead of doing this every time?

```
String str = "{\"33\":\"7153\", \"170\":\"AA\",\"151\":10}";
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(str);
Product s = new Product();

if (json.has("33")) s.setCode(json.getString("33"));
if (json.has("170")) s.setName(json.getString("170"));
if (json.has("151")) s.setPointer(json.getString("151"));
if (json.has("98")) s.setPrice(json.getString("98"));
if (json.has("rate")) s.setRate(json.getString("rate"));
if (json.has("132")) s.setValue(json.getString("132"));
if (json.has("45")) s.setDescription(json.getString("45"));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Google Gson.

```
public class Product {
    @SerializedName("33") private String code;
    @SerializedName("170") private String name;
    @SerializedName("151") private String pointer;
    @SerializedName("98") private String price;
    @SerializedName("rate") private String rate;
    @SerializedName("132") private String value;
    @SerializedName("45") private String description;
    // setters, getters
}
```

And

```
    String str = "{\"33\":\"7153\", \"170\":\"AA\",\"151\":10}";
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    Product s = gson.fromJson(str, Product.class);
```

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly what i was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

in each  setCode(string x), setName(string x), setPointer(string x), setPrice(string x)... give a check:
if(x == null)
  return;

then when parsing Json you don't have to check Json's response have which key or not.

Comment: i guess it won't improve performance much when i have to parse a few hundreds every minute. Thanks anyway.